# Excel Tooltip on Mouse Over for ActiveX command button

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I feel like this should be a simple question but I cannot find the answer anywhere. I build a macro and assigned it to an ActiveX command button and I just want a simple tooltip that displays when your mouse hovers over the button.

(I would prefer it to stay an ActiveX command button if possible)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

found [there](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/control-text-tip-for-command-button.846093/)

Follow these steps:

1 Insert an ActiveX command button on Sheet1. Name it CommandButton1.

2 Insert a text box shape on Sheet1. Name it TextBox1.

3 In TextBox1, type some text (e.g. "Click me").

4 In the VB Editor, insert a class module. Name it clsButton.

5 Type the following code into the clsButton module:

Code:

```
 Public WithEvents Btn As MSForms.CommandButton

 Private Sub Btn_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal    X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Textbox1")
     .Visible = msoTrue
     .Top = Y + Me.Btn.Top
     .Left = X + Me.Btn.Left
   End With
  Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "HideIt"
  End Sub
```

6 Insert an ordinary code module. Name it Module1.

7 Type the following code into Module1:

Code:

```
  Dim Cmd As New clsButton

  Private Sub ConnectObject()
     Set Cmd.Btn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Object
  End Sub

  Private Sub HideIt()
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Textbox1").Visible = msoFalse
  End Sub
```

8 Run the "ConnectObject" procedure.

9 In Excel, move the mouse cursor over the command button and watch what happens...